# Data format separate

Tags: android, xml

Data:

```
<QPDB name='My name' age='25'>
```

Java code:

```
String st = "<QPDB name='My name' age='25'>"
```

This above data is getting from After QR code scan. How can I separately get the `name` and `age` attributes in Android.

I want to get data like below:

```
name='My name'
```

Comment: This is the string format: <QPDB name='my name' age='21'>

Comment: I've corrected the formatting for you, XML elements won't appear unless the line is formatted for code (i.e. starts with 4 spaces).

Comment: you could use `String.split()` by `'` character, and in the result array `name` value will be under `1` index, and `age` value will be under `3` index. Also you can try parsing it as XML using some XML parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String mainText = "<QPDB name='My name' age='25'>";

String[] splittedText = mainText.split("'");

String name = "name=" + "\'" + splittedText[1] + "\'";
String age = "age=" + "\'" + splittedText[3] + "\'";

System.out.println(name);
System.out.println(age);

**Output**
name='My name'
age='25'
```